# How can I make CXF ignore HTTP bindings?

Tags: soap, wsdl, cxf

I'm currently trying to understand a WSDL file I've been given and why CXF (using CXF-2.7.17) would not generate a JAX-WS compliant class for this services. Here's an excerpt from the WSDL file:

```
<wsdl:portType name="ServiceSoap">
<wsdl:operation name="GetClient">
  <wsdl:input message="tns:GetClientSoapIn" />
  <wsdl:output message="tns:GetClientSoapOut" />
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:portType name="ServiceHttpPost">
<wsdl:operation name="GetClient">
  <wsdl:input message="tns:GetClientHttpPostIn" />
  <wsdl:output message="tns:GetClientHttpPostOut" />
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>

<wsdl:binding name="ServiceSoap" type="tns:ServiceSoap">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
<wsdl:operation name="GetClient">
  <soap:operation soapAction="http://ws.comp.com/GetClient" style="document" />
  <wsdl:input>
    <soap:body use="literal" />
    <soap:header message="tns:GetClientCreds" part="Creds" use="literal" />
  </wsdl:input>
  <wsdl:output>
    <soap:body use="literal" />
  </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>

<wsdl:binding name="ServiceHttpPost" type="tns:ServiceHttpPost">
<http:binding verb="POST" />
<wsdl:operation name="GetClient">
  <http:operation location="/GetClient" />
  <wsdl:input>
    <mime:content type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" />
  </wsdl:input>
  <wsdl:output>
    <mime:mimeXml part="Body" />
  </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
```

The gist is, I have a WSDL file that contains more then my SOAP bindings, which I want CXF to turn into an actual service.

Using `WSDL2Java` on this WSDL file, I get the following stacktrace:

```
line 3168 column 66 of file:/home/user/test/Service.wsdl: cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'part' must appear on element 'mime:content'.
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.validator.internal.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:203)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.validator.internal.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:119)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.validator.internal.SchemaValidator.isValid(SchemaValidator.java:103)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.validator.internal.WSDL11Validator.isValid(WSDL11Validator.java:157)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.wsdl11.JAXWSDefinitionBuilder.validate(JAXWSDefinitionBuilder.java:206)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.processWsdl(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:204)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:164)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:412)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:103)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:113)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:86)
    [...]
```

It complains about the line

```
<mime:content type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" />
```

Which apparently comes from the [cxf's built-in xsd](https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/master/core/src/main/resources/schemas/wsdl/mime-binding.xsd) complying to [WS-I attachment profile](http://www.ws-i.org/profiles/attachmentsprofile-1.0-2004-08-24.html#MIME_Binding_Schema_Fixes), which requires `part` to be present (in contrast to the WSDL-1.1 spec).

Thus my question is:

**Can I make the validator ignore these bindings?**